# Database or File System to Server / Accept Short Audio Clips?

Tags: database, filesystems, java, tomcat6

I am working on an application that will allow users to play short audio clips (voice recordings), as well upload short clips. I will be using a Java / Tomcat environment.  I am wondering if this type of data belongs in a database or a filesystem.  I have read on here that the file system is the better choice for performance reasons, but a database seems like it would be more manageable.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

A filesystem is just as manageable as a database.  Putting this sort of data into a database is just asking for trouble -- any time you need to access that data, you'll need to extract it from the database into a file before being able to work on it.  Just skip the middleman and put it in files right from the start.